# How do I use Xcode to codesign a command line utility I created with SPM?

Tags: code-signing, swift-package-manager, xcode-command-line-tools

I created a command line utility using swift package init, and added swift-argument-parser as a dependency.

Steps:

- Create a folder for my project and cd into it in terminal
- Issue the command `swift package init --type executable` in terminal:
- Edit the Package.swift file to add a dependency on swift-argument-parser. (Thie details of this step are beyond the scope of this question.)
- Open the Package.swift file from the finder, or issue the command `xed Package.swift` in terminal. (Either approach opens my package in the Xcode IDE)

I have my command line utiliyt built, and now I want to code-sign it and distribute it. I'd like to sign it in xcode rather than signing it from terminal. How do I do that?

Apple has [documentation on adding a certificate to an Xcode project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/sharing-your-teams-signing-certificates) and signing Mac code for distribution, but those docs assume a "normal" xcode project that has an xcode project file (`.xcodeproj`.) Projects build from an SPM `Project.swift` file don't have a `.xcodeproj` file, and so they don't present settings that you can edit.

I guess I could go back and recreate my tool as a normal xcode project, or figure out how to sign it from the command line, but I prefer to use the IDE where possible, and would rather not start my project over from scratch.